How to Log a Window Object?
I need to obtain the values that services like Cloudflare check in the window object. Therefore, I am trying to capture which value is being requested from the window object whenever any value is requested. For example, when the window.screen.availWidth value is requested, I should log that the screen.availWidth value is being requested. This can be done using any tool like Puppeteer, Selenium, etc.
I tried to proxy the window object with the 'new Proxy' feature, but I was not successful. No logs appear in the console.
const originalWindow = window;

function logAccess(property) {
  console.trace(`Erişilen window özelliği: ${property}`);
}

window = new Proxy(originalWindow, {
  get: function(target, property) {
    logAccess(property);
    return target[property];
  }
});

